# Apache NIFI - How to wait for SQL Insert full completion

Tags: apache-nifi, wait

I wanted to wait until 'ExecuteSQL' processor finishes inserting big file into SQL database (table: bu_service_template), then move to other section.'ExecuteSQL' processor inserts row by row content of a file. I wanted to wait until file is fully inserted and then move to a next file.

My current flow:

[FLOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsV4R.png)

[Update attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KDQZ.png)

[MergeContent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv85k.png)

[Wait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3UKL.png)

I wanted to wait until file is fully inserted and then move to a next file.

Comment: Check documentation: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.19.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html `Merge Strategy:  Defragment`